# Where is the documentation for Tabs

Tags: bokeh

I want to know how to work with the `Tabs` widget. Where can I find the online documentation (v1.1.0)?

```py
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs
help(Tabs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation about tabs can be found on [this](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#tab-panes) page.